# How can I count the number of

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

On our Postgres Database we would like to count the number of bookings we have per day since the beginning of time.

For Now we have the following query:

```
SELECT 
   to_char("domain".bookings.created_at,'dy') AS "Name of the day",
   COUNT ("domain".bookings."id") AS "Number of bookings"
FROM
   "domain".bookings
GROUP BY
   to_char("domain".bookings.created_at,'dy'), 
   "domain".bookings."id"
ORDER BY
   "domain".bookings."id"
```

Unfortunately it is returning the following results:

```
tue 1
wed 1
wed 1
sun 1
sat 1
thu 1
wed 1
tue 1
```

Instead of the total per day.

Is there a way to change the formula?

Thank you!

Luca

Comment: remove ` "domain".bookings."id"` from `group by`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the group by that's causing your problem. You don't want to group by your aggregated fields

```
SELECT 
   to_char("domain".bookings.created_at,'dy') AS "Name of the day",
   COUNT ("domain".bookings."id") AS "Number of bookings"
FROM
   "domain".bookings
GROUP BY
   to_char("domain".bookings.created_at,'dy')
ORDER BY
   to_char("domain".bookings.created_at,'dy')
```

Comment: To clarify: everything that you `GROUP BY` defines a distinct group in the output. By including `id` as a group-field, you get a group for every one, and of course, each group contains one member!

Comment: Thank you! Very clear with the explanations, I got it now!

Answer (score 2):

Your grouping seems wrong. Try:

```
SELECT 
   to_char("domain".bookings.created_at,'dy') AS "Name of the day",
   COUNT ("domain".bookings."id") AS "Number of bookings"
FROM
   "domain".bookings
GROUP BY
   to_char("domain".bookings.created_at,'dy')
ORDER BY
   "Number of bookings"
```